# Prevent browserify from including module's dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I'd like to use my NodeJS module in the browser - so I'm using `browserify` to process it.

Now, how can I stop `browserify` from including the module's dependencies in the bundle file? In this case the dependency is `lodash` and I'll be loading it separately in the `index.html`.

Here's what I've got so far:

index.html

```
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
<script src="my-module.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
var _ = require('lodash');

_.each([0, 1, 2], function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

gulp.js

```
var browserify = require('browserify'),
  source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  return browserify()
    .require('./index.js', {
      expose: 'my-module'
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('my-module.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to load it separately? The main goal of browserify is to bundle everything...

Comment: Well, the front-end app (index.html) already has lodash `_` as global.

Comment: Maybe you should change the front-end app? Leaking globals isn't exactly a best-practice.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree, I have an Angular SPA with `angular` and `lodash` as globals. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Bundling everything makes development easier, but why would you want to bundle dependencies during a deployment? Most common libraries are already hosted on Google and Cloudflare's CDNs; furthermore, users' browsers probably have these libs cached already. You lose that speed advantage by bundling everything.

Comment: SO isn't really a great discussion platform. My feeling is that most of the time it's probably a micro-optimization to worry about that. If you've got time for it, go for it, but presumably you're own deployed files are permacached anyway, so the gain of a few 10s of kb is likely not the core of your performance issues, especially since many sites are much more bottlenecked on time-to-first-byte and other perf issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`browserify-shim` offers the option of setting up globals.

Here are the changes I've made to my code.

package.json

```
{
  "browserify-shim": {
    "lodash": "global:_"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
  }
}
```

gulp.js

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  return browserify('./index.js')
    .require('./index.js', {
      expose: 'my-module'
    })
    .transform('browserify-shim', {
      global: true
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an option to exclude files:

> Usage: browserify [entry files] {OPTIONS}
> [...]
> --ignore, -i  Replace a file with an empty stub. Files can be globs.
> --exclude, -u  Omit a file from the output bundle. Files can be globs.

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage

And the corresponding `exclude` function:

> b.exclude(file)
>
> Prevent the module name or file at file from showing up in the output bundle.
>
> If your code tries to require() that file it will throw unless you've provided another mechanism for loading it.

So you should try this:

```
return browserify()
  .require('./index.js', {
    expose: 'my-module'
  })
  .exclude('lodash.js')
  .bundle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

```
const nodeOnlyModule = eval('require')('module-name');
```

This way you can trick browserify.

Comment: Note: Using `eval()` is discouraged.